# How do you check if an SSRS report was executed by a user or an automatic refresh in the SSRS SQL database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

How do you check if an SSRS report was executed by a user or an automatic refresh in the SSRS SQL database?

I'm assuming the answer is in the ExecutionLog table or something it links to, but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

A query to start with:

```
    SELECT  Path Path ,
            Name Name ,
            CreatedBy.UserName CreatedBy ,
            COUNT(DISTINCT ExecutionLog.UserName) DistinctUserCount ,
            COUNT(ExecutionLog.UserName) ExecutionCount
    FROM    Catalog
            LEFT JOIN Users CreatedBy ON CreatedBy.UserID = Catalog.CreatedByID
            LEFT JOIN ExecutionLog ON Catalog.ItemID = ExecutionLog.ReportID
    GROUP BY Path ,
            Name ,
            CreatedBy.UserName
    ORDER BY Path ,
            Name ,
            CreatedBy.UserName
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean as a result of setting the `AutoRefresh` property to a non zero value in the report definition then having the user open the report, and have the report refresh itself?

Comment: Yes, exactly.

Example:

User loads a report that has a non zero AutoRefresh value
User leaves report open util it automatically refreshes once
The report will have 2 new entries in the ExecutionLog table

In this example, is there any way to contrast the original execution event (where the user loaded the report manually), to the second event (where the report automatically refreshed)

Comment: Sorry I can't tell you but I suspect not as both of these events are initiated by the client.